# HttpResponse: failed to respond when benchmarking vert.x application

Tags: java, concurrency, benchmarking, vert.x

I built a REST web service using vert.x
my machine has 8 CPU, and i'm running a single vertical with 16 instances

This service has only 1 endpoint - POST 'execute'. this code is calling a 3rd party,
so I run it as blockingHandler, and it can take 4-30 seconds to return.

I want to be able to support 1,000 concurrent requests at a time.
I started to make some performance and load tests, but for some reason, after ~100 requests i'm
starting to get:

> Response code: Non HTTP response code:
>   org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException   Response message: Non HTTP
>   response message: localhost:9999 failed to respond

I tried to do the following:

- I put a single vertical with a single instance.

  - I wrote a java code which runs 10/20/30.../100 concurrent threads which each make a POST request
  - 90 requests were good, most of the time 100 also. when i tried 105,110 I start getting those failures.
  - I changed to Jmeter, same issue with the same numbers there.
  - Switched to ab and wrk - same issue.
  - I tested same thing on my 16 instances env - again, same numbers
  - It looks like no matter what connection timeout or request timeout I'm putting, after 20 seconds the client just "give up"

The most interesting thing here, is that vert.x continue to work and complete the requests successfully, even
for the request which failed.

I'm guessing it's something with the network maybe, I changed computers, I changed linux/Mac,
all the time I'm getting the same results.

anyone has an idea?

Comment: Please post the code that handles the message server side. Also, does the server call the end() function on the response?

Comment: I can't post the original code, so i simulate it a little bit (this code also create the errors):

            router.post("/dummy").blockingHandler(r-> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                r.response().setStatusCode(200).end("OK");
            });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `blockingHandler`, you're shooting yourself in the leg. In both legs, actually.

What you need to do:

1. Use a regular route handler
2. Send you message through EventBus to WorkerVerticle
3. Do your network call there
4. Return results over EventBus with `reply()`
5. Call end()